# RAM not performing at speed possible, have tried XMP

Tags: memory, performance, motherboard

So I have 16GB of DDR3 RAM (brand I can't remember:/)

on an ASUS Crosshair V - Formula Z MB

However even when I enabled XMP I still can't get the RAM to run faster than 720 which is strange as the RAM can work at 1800 :/

OS W10

CPU AMD FX 8350 Black

MB Asus Crosshair V - Formula Z

RAM 16GB (Corsair CMY16GX3M2A1866C9R Vengeance Pro Series 16GB (2x8GB) DDR3 1866Mhz CL9 XMP Performance Desktop Memory Kit Red)

Comment: XMP doesn't necessarily specify the highest possible frequency of the RAM module, as they often are only reached by manual overclocking (and increasing the RAM Voltage) and therefore, XMP serves more as a guide than as a solution (in my experience, that is).

Comment: how is it that you are determining that your RAM is operating at a specific frequency?

Comment: @FrankThomas I use a program call Speccy https://www.piriform.com/speccy/download which shows me temps, speed etc

Comment: 1866Mhz is only available in a dual channel configuration. have you confirmed that your chips are in the right slots to form a dual-channel set?

Comment: @flolilolilo so are you saying I'm going to have to mess with the Voltage manually, crap... would rather not roast my RAM but if that's what it takes..

Comment: @DavidGolding deleted the part with spec-request, as I was confused by browsing different sites, sorry.
I would suggest you read this: https://superuser.com/a/703688/703240
FYI, CPU-Z specifies the correct number (that is: the number I would expect) with my 2400 MHz RAMs on an ASUS X99-A

Comment: @flolilolilo all good I deleted my comment when I saw your update :)

Comment: @FrankThomas Should be I followed the manual but it's something to double check when I get home

Comment: No roasting needed *if* you proceed with caution.
Read through the [specifications](http://www.corsair.com/en-gb/vengeance-pro-series-16gb-2-x-8gb-ddr3-dram-1866mhz-c9-memory-kit-cmy16gx3m2a1866c9r) and then set the values in your BIOS manually. I'd then try [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) and see if it works - if not, I'd increase the voltage by 1 increment (usually 0.01V, I guess) until all works fine.
I'dd also suggest you read some guides such as [this one](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ram-overclocking-guide,4693.html). And of course, Frank has a point with checking slots.

Comment: @flolilolilo thanks will give this a go when I get home.

Comment: CPU-Z indicates the XMP profiles, and the voltage required, you shouldn't have to guess what voltage is required to run at your desired speeds

Comment: @Ramhound true that, but sometimes, the XMP settings are a more "stable" preset (like 1600 MHz) or sometimes, they are a bitt off (that, of course, is quite uncommon and may depend on the used mainboard). I for one own some RAM that would consistently deliver bluescreens with the 2400MHz XMP-Preset on my machine, but when I specified everything manually (to the same values), everything works fine.

Comment: Sorry might be being an idiot here, but what do I do with this info? https://valid.x86.fr/v0ks13 @flolilolilo

Comment: Frequency 959.8 MHz -  sounds like it works (you have to multiply the frequency by 2)

Comment: ok awesome thanks for all the help, I was just being an idiot lol @flolilolilo